# Last post was 7 days ago, not 75 days ago

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

In chat, I click on a user's picture, hover over one room (which was inactive for a long time), and the tooltip says "last post 75 days ago". Entering the room I saw that the last post was only 7 days ago.

[image: Example]

Room is **[PHP Internals](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34770/php-internals)**

Comment: No freehand circles :(

Comment: @JoshMein: Freehand circles added.

Comment: Someone should create "freehand circle" tools for image editors...

Comment: Those "freehand" circles look suspiciously symmetrical. Did you use a template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the last post in the room, it's the last post (and total posts) by *that particular user* in that room, since the menu is in the context of the selected user.

With that in mind, looking at a few examples suggests the numbers are indeed correct, making this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).